# TheadLocal for local member variable

Tags: java

Can we make ThreadLocal on primitive memeber variable?

Something like we do it for Wrapper,

```
private ThreadLocal<Integer> time = new ThreadLocal<Integer> ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, primitive values aren't treated as objecs. In particular you can't create references to them. This is exactly why we need wrappers. So you can't have `ThreadLocal<int>`, just as you can't have `List<int>`...